# Sort and update list of objects based on variable change

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, int

I am working on a algorithm which will solve a problem I have, but I am finding myself a little stuck. Here is the scenario:

I have an object which contains a variable called order.

```
public class Item
{
     public int Order{get; set;};

     public int ID{get; set;}; // not incremented can be any value!
}
```

So I have a list of these:

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>().OrderBy((o) => o.Order);
```

And at any time the order value can be changed. 
So if I want to change the first an items order value all other order values should update accordingly so there are no duplicates.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= list .Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (list [i].ID == inputID)
    {
        list [i].Order = inputNewPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        if (list [i].Order < inputNewPosition)
        {
            list [i].Order --;
        }
        else
        {
             list [i].Order ++;
        }
    }
}
```

This fails if I change the last item order to be the first, as this would make the first item order be 0!

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: **So if I want to change the first an items order value all other order values should update accordingly so there are no duplicates** crashed my parser.  maybe you want to rephrase?

Comment: I'm looking for clarification: From what I am reading I gather you have 5 objects with the order attributes of 1,2,3,4,5 and you want to be able to change the object with Order=5 to something like order=3 and change 3->4 and change 4->5 to make room for it. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us look at the four situations for an element in your list (as we iterate through them). If (for terseness) we take `old` to be the item that is moving's old position and `new` to be its new position we have the following cases for an item in your list (draw them out on paper to make this clear).

1. the current item is the one to be moved: move it directly
2. the current item's order is < `new` and < `old`: don't move it
3. the current item's order is ≥ `new` and < `old`: move it right
4. the current item's order is ≤ `new` and > `old`: move it left
5. the current item's order is > `new` and > `old`: don't move it

When we start enumerating, we know the where the item to be moved will end up (at `new`) but we do not know where it has come from (`old`). However, as we start our enumeration at the *beginning* of the list, we know at each step that it must be further down in the list until we have actually seen it! So we can use a flag (`seen`) to say whether we have seen it yet. So `seen` of false means < `old` whilst true means >= `old`.

```
bool seen = false;
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    if (items[i].ID == inputID)
    {
        items[i].Order = inputNewPosition;
        seen = true;
    }
}
```

This flag tells us whether the current item is >= *old*. So now can start shunting stuff around based on this knowledge and the above rules. (So `new` in the above discussion is `inputNewPosition` and whether we are before or after `old` we represent with our `seen` variable.)

```
bool seen;
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    if (items[i].ID == inputID) // case 1
    {
        items[i].Order = inputNewPosition;
        seen = true;
    }
    else if (seen) // cases 4 & 5
    {
        if (items[i].Order <= inputNewPosition) // case 4
        {
           items[i].Order--; // move it left
        }
    }
    else // case 2 & 3
    {
        if (items[i].Order >= inputNewPosition) // case 3
        {
            items[i].Order++; // move it right
        }            
    }
}
```

Having said all of that, it is probably simpler to sort the collection on each change. The default sorting algorithm should be quite nippy with a nearly sorted collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but for the requirements you'd likely be best off doing an event on the object that contains Order, and possibly having a container object which can monitor that.  However I'd suspect that you might want to rethink your algorithm if that's the case, as it seems a very awkward way to deal with the problem of displaying in order.

That said, what is the problem requirement?  If I switch the order of item #2 to #5, what should happen to #3?  Does it remain where it is, or should it be #6?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem but I think there might be a more clever way out there..

The object that I need to update are policy workload items.  Each one of these has a priority associated.  There cannot be a policy workload item with the same priority.  So when a user updates the priority the other priorities need to shift up or down accordingly.

This handler takes a request object. The request has an id and a priority.

```cs
 public class UpdatePriorityCommand
 {
     public int PolicyWorkloadItemId { get; set; }
     public int Priority { get; set; }
 }
```

This class represents the **request** object in the following code.

```cs
//Get the item to change priority
PolicyWorkloadItem policyItem = await _ctx.PolicyWorkloadItems
                                          .FindAsync(request.PolicyWorkloadItemId);

//Get that item's priority and assign it to oldPriority variable
int oldPriority = policyItem.Priority.Value;

//Get the direction of change. 
//-1 == moving the item up in list
//+1 == moving the item down in list
int direction = oldPriority < request.Priority ? -1 : 1;

//Get list of items to update... 
List<PolicyWorkloadItem> policyItems = await _ctx.PolicyWorkloadItems
                                                 .Where(x => x.PolicyWorkloadItemId != request.PolicyWorkloadItemId)
                                                 .ToListAsync();

//Loop through and update values
foreach(var p in policyItems)
{
    //if moving item down in list (I.E. 3 to 1) then only update
    //items that are less than the old priority. (I.E. 1 to 2 and 2 to 3)
    //items greater than the new priority need not change (i.E. 4,5,6... etc.)

    //if moving item up in list (I.E. 1 to 3)
    //items less than or equal to the new value get moved down. (I.E. 2 to 1 and 3 to 2)
    //items greater than the new priority need not change (i.E. 4,5,6... etc.)
    if(
           (direction > 0 && p.Priority < oldPriority)
        || (direction < 0 && p.Priority > oldPriority && p.Priority <= request.Priority)
      )
    {  
        p.Priority += direction;
        _ctx.PolicyWorkloadItems.Update(p);
    }       
}

//finally update the priority of the target item directly
policyItem.Priority = request.Priority;

//track changes with EF Core
_ctx.PolicyWorkloadItems.Update(policyItem);

//Persist changes to database
await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```