# change and update order of generic list items with C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics, generic-list

I am working on an algorithm that answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880897/7013518) which solve specific problems, but I want to make this algorithm generic to use it for any type of lists that I have in my application. but I am stuck in.

for example: I have a Scenario class which contains a variable called Order:

```
public class Scenario
{
 public int Id{get; set;}; // not incremented can be any value!
 public int Order{get; set;};
 public string Title{get; set;};
}
```

and I can call this method to change the order of any scenario as I want:

```
private void UpdateOrders(Scenario targetScenario, short newOrder, List<Scenario> items)
{
        items = items.OrderBy(_ => _.Order).ToList();
        bool seen = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].Id == targetScenario.Id)
            {
                items[i].Order = newOrder;
                seen = true;
            }
            else if (seen)
            {
                if (items[i].Order <= newOrder)
                {
                    items[i].Order--; // move it left
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (items[i].Order >= newOrder)
                {
                    items[i].Order++; // move it right
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and this works for any other specific lists, but this algorithm must be repeated each time to update order of each list.  so I try to extend this algorithm to avoid writing duplicate code.
here what I try but obviously its not working:

```
private void UpdateOrders<T>(T targetScenario, short newOrder, List<T> items)
    {
        items = items.OrderBy(_ => _.Order).ToList();
        bool seen = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].Id == targetScenario.Id)
            {
                items[i].Order = newOrder;
                seen = true;
            }
            else if (seen)
            {
                if (items[i].Order <= newOrder)
                {
                    items[i].Order--; // move it left
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (items[i].Order >= newOrder)
                {
                    items[i].Order++; // move it right
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: By "not working" do you mean you get any particular error message?

Comment: yes, I faced with Compiler Error CS1061. @David

Comment: Looks like the algo relies on `int Id` and `int Order` ; make an interface IWhatever with these props that your other objects also with Id and Order can thus implement and switch the algo to working off IWhatevers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a contract where you can ensure the items you use have a property of `int Order`. Then restrict your function `T` type to be of your contract type.

```
public interface ISortable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Order { get; set; }
}

public class Scenario : ISortable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}


private void UpdateOrders<T>(T targetScenario, short newOrder, List<T> items) where T : ISortable
{
    items = items.OrderBy(_ => _.Order).ToList();
    bool seen = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].Id == targetScenario.Id)
        {
            items[i].Order = newOrder;
            seen = true;
        }
        else if (seen)
        {
            if (items[i].Order <= newOrder)
            {
                items[i].Order--; // move it left
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (items[i].Order >= newOrder)
            {
                items[i].Order++; // move it right
            }
        }
    }
}
```